# How to retain search menu text in fragments while replacing another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-menu

I have a "fragment A" having a search menu and a search listener with it. The listener is working as expected. However, what I am trying to achieve is, when I will go away from this "fragment A" and come back to it, I would like to get the search menu expanded with the previous search query. Currently, when I replace the fragment, the query listener is called and it sends an empty string in the `onQueryTextChange` method.

The example of what I did is,

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        message.setOnClickListener {
            parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, BlankFragment()).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView?

        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                query?.let { Log.d("zzz", it) }
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                newText?.let { Log.d("zzzzz", it) }
                return false
            }

        })
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

Is there any standard way of achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could save the query to SharedPreferences then make an onResume method in your fragment. When in onResume, load the string from the SharedPreferences instead of recreating it

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I dont think that's a good way to achieve this.